# Flutter ListView of data from API does not show on my web app

Tags: api, listview, flutter, web-applications

Hello i try to create a listView of element from data of an API for my flutter web project. I get no result showing on the page each time i try. I was supposed to show a ListView of French department; I tried to use a code more basic for desperately trying to have results on my page. So I try to use a more simple code than mine to see how it work but still have no result(Blank page under appBar). I don't think I understand really well how that's supposed to worked but I find out a tutorial that had a sample code of a random ListView of element from data of an API; but this also don't work I'm a little bit stressed out... Is there a problem with this code ? Can I have more explanation about how to get data from an API and display them on a ListView on Flutter? Thank you everyone for the help

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

const baseUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

class API {
  static Future getUsers() {
    var url = baseUrl + "/users";
    return http.get(url);
  }
}


class User {
  int id;
  String name;
  String email;

  User(int id, String name, String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
  }

  User.fromJson(Map json)
      : id = json['id'],
        name = json['name'],
        email = json['email'];

  Map toJson() {
    return {'id': id, 'name': name, 'email': email};
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'My Http App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyListScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MyListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _MyListScreenState();
}

class _MyListScreenState extends State {
  var users = new List<User>();

  _getUsers() {
    API.getUsers().then((response) {
      setState(() {
        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        users = list.map((model) => User.fromJson(model)).toList();
      });
    });
  }

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUsers();
  }

  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("User List"),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: users.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(title: Text(users[index].name));
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Answer (score 0):

Try using async and await on getUsers:

```
static Future getUsers() async {
  var url = baseUrl + "/users";
  return await http.get(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and everything is okay, you just need to add a ProgressIndicator.
Things to note:

- Show a CircularProgressIndicator when making API calls
- Separate your model class and API calls classes (put them in different files for quick 
  future modifications)
- Use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for tasks than take long to execute (async tasks)

For your current implementation, modify as follows:

1. Initialize loading

   class _MyListScreenState extends State {
    var users = new List();
    bool _isLoading = true;

2.Update state when loading is complete

```
  _getUsers() {
  API.getUsers().then((response) {
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
    Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
    users = list.map((model) => User.fromJson(model)).toList();
   });
 });
 }
```

3. Add widget in your build method

```
  body: _isLoading
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: users.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(title: Text(users[index].name));
            },
          ));
```